# Symfony + Api-platform релейшен многие ко многим (машины <=> пользователи) как ограничить доступ, что бы пользователь мог получить только свои машины

Tags: php, api, symfony, symfony4

```
   /**
 * @Groups({"car_read", "car_write"})
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="cars")
 */
public $users;

/**
 * @return Collection|User[]
 */
public function getUsers(): Collection
{
    return $this->users;
}

public function addUser(User $user): self
{
    if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
        $this->users[] = $user;
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeUser(User $user): self
{
    if ($this->users->contains($user)) {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }

    return $this;
}



    /**
 * @Groups({"user_write", "user_read"})
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Car", mappedBy="users")
 */
private $cars;

public function __construct($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->cars = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->userData = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addCar(Car $car): self
{
    if (!$this->cars->contains($car)) {
        $this->cars->add($car);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeCar(Car $Cars): bool
{
    return $this->cars->removeElement($Cars);
}

public function getCars(): Collection
{
    return $this->cars;
}
```

[image: У данной машины есть юзер, это запрос на получение всех машин, ограничение я хочу поставить в itemOperations getъ]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: При попытке получить машину используя юзера которому принадлежит эта машина получаю форбиден]